# Clicking in Xcode 4 emulator is offset!

Tags: iphone, xcode4, click

I have a navigation bar controller + tab bar controller + UITableview for the first view of my app and within there, everything is fine.  But when i click one of the table cells, i do a pushViewController with the navigationcontroller and it shows a view controller (the tab bar and navigation bar still show of course). but only within this view, i need to click about 60 px above my target to trigger the click event.  Even for the navigation bar "Back" button, I need to click the very top of the iphone screen to go back.

Has anybody experienced this before!? i have no idea what is wrong

Comment: Have you tried restarting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this happens when you put buttons directly on a window.  I'll stick to keeping everything on views